# LDAP olcAccess regex are not working as expected

Tags: regex, spring-security, permissions, ldap, ldif

I have a LDAP server runnign with the Structure:

```
dc=example,dc=ldap
   dc=organisations
      o=orga1 (objectClasses top/organisation/dcObject)
         cn=ADMINS (objectClasses top/groupOfNames)
         cn=USER
      o=orga2 
         cn=ADMIN
         cn=USER
      cn=users (objectClasses top/organisation/dcObject)
         cn=user1 (objectClasses top/person)
         cn=user2
```

Now I whant to add some rules that only the users in the organisation groups are able to see the organisation.

the hard coded approach was quite easy to implement:

```
olcAccess: {1}to dn.subtree="o=orga1,dc=organizations,dc=example,dc=ldap"
  by group.exact="cn=ADMINS,o=orga1,dc=organizations,dc=example,dc=ldap" write
  by group.exact="cn=USER,o=orga1,dc=organizations,dc=example,dc=ldap" read
  by * none
```

(It is important to write TWO spaces in front of the 'by' [It was an problem for a long time for me])

But I don't whant to implement these rules for every new organisation, so I tried to implement the rule with some regex magig. But I failed misserably:

```
olcAccess: {1}to dn.regex="^o(.+),dc=organizations,dc=example,dc=ldap$"
  attrs=children
  by group.exact="cn=ADMINS,o=[$1],dc=organizations,dc=example,dc=ldap$" write
  by group.exact="cn=USER,o=[$1],dc=organizations,dc=example,dc=ldap$" read
  by * none
```

This rule affects nothing.
So does someone have some idea to fix my problematic?

Or is it not possible to group the members like I did?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over the mailinglist I've got the hint that group.exact, is NOT doing regex evaluation.

As a workarround, I've created my own objectClass with the attributes
"orgaMember" and "orgaAdmin" now it is possible to create a olcAccess rule based on these attributes. To apply this rule to all organizations a regex can be used.

```
olcAccess: {1}to dn.regex="^o=(.+),dc=organizations,dc=example,dc=ldap$"
 by dnattr=orgaAdmin write
 by dnattr=orgaMember read
 by * none
```

I hope this will help someone.

PS. to update the objectClasses a lot of things need to be noticed.
see http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/slapd-config.html